# Int is handled as string in PHP on CentOS 7.1 and Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, unix, centos

I develop on a Windows system and use the `!==` comparison a lot to ensure that both the value and the type are as expected. I just had issues with that (the comparison was failing) and just found out that values of the type int (in mysql) are handled as strings.

On Windows it looks like this:

```
Order {#488 ▼
  #table: "orders"
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #hidden: []
  #fillable: array:9 [▶]
  #dates: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:14 [▼
    "id" => 6
    "currency_id" => 1
    "user_id" => 1
    "coupon_id" => 1
    "status" => 2
    "created_at" => "2017-06-26 00:37:44"
    "updated_at" => "2017-06-26 00:37:50"
    "deleted_at" => null
  ]
```

on CentOS like this:

```
Order {#488 ▼
  #table: "orders"
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #hidden: []
  #fillable: array:9 [▶]
  #dates: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:14 [▼
    "id" => "6"
    "currency_id" => "1"
    "user_id" => "1"
    "coupon_id" => "1"
    "status" => "2"
    "created_at" => "2017-06-26 00:37:44"
    "updated_at" => "2017-06-26 00:37:50"
    "deleted_at" => null
  ]
```

I really don't know what could be causing this. Please let me know what additional info would be required to find this out. Since I have no idea at all, I don't know exactly what might be relevant.

Additional Info:

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and printed this information by using Laravel's `dd()` method. The data is an instance of an Eloquent Model.

Comment: You should know by now that this isn't enough. How do you view these structures and arrays? How do you populate them? Just seeing some printout says nothing about what could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but as mentioned, I have no idea where to start, therefore I did not post too much information. I will update the question with answers to your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could simply be some slight difference in the underlying extensions that interact with your database, or some implementation difference (version difference?) in the abstraction layers in between that and your code. It's hard to tell with such limited info.

However, in general, in PHP you should assume that database values are passed to you as strings, even if they are actually integers/floats/booleans within the database. Assume that you need to do type checking and (if needed) type casting on your own.

I'd also caution you against excessive strict checking in PHP. I get why you'd want to do that, and in most other languages I'd be right there with you, but one of PHP's defining characteristics is it's indifference to native types and it's ability to automatically juggle between them, so within that language you shouldn't try to force type strictness too much.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it was the mysql server itself that casted it to a string, or better said the PDO extension. I got it fixed now.

I will also do some research in regards to this strict comparison in PHP. I'm used to that from other languages and never saw an issue with that in PHP (since now), thanks for the hint!